# Concatenate Rows Grouping By Categories

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I'm having an attribute table like this of a shapefile on QGIS:

Movie / Actor

A   /    1

A    /   2

A    /   3

B    /   4

I want to get the name of a movie and all actors in that movie, and I want the result to be in a format like this:

Movie /  ActorList

A   /    1, 2, 3

B    /   4

How can I do it?

Comment: Which kind of geoprocessing are you thinking to modify the attribute table grouping observations like this?

Comment: We do this in PostgreSQL using the string_agg() function... I *think* is similar to the QGIS aggregate function though I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work

Comment: The table ahead is just an example. I want to dissolve a feature based on the categoriy (MOVIE) and create a new column with all the other attributes concatenated (ActorsList). The real situation is that i have multiple polygons with the category CITIES and the attributes like FOREST, URBAN AREAS, ETC. I want to dissolve with the field CITIES and bring in another column all the attributes of the original shapefile.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4):

As [DPSSpatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9880/dpsspatial) commented, QGIS aggregate function has `concatenate()`.

Just make sure the `Output field length` is long enough.

[image]

Expression is: 
    `concatenate("Actor", group_by:="Movie", concatenator:=', ')`

[image]